# How to delete user roles?

Tags: user-roles, buddypress, customization

I installed BuddyPress which created additional user roles but even after deleting BuddyPress those roles are still there. How can I delete these roles? I have tried the `remove_role()` command but it did not work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$wp_roles = new WP_Roles(); // create new role object
$wp_roles->remove_role('name_of_role');
```

If you need to check the **name_of_role** use

```
$wp_roles->get_names();
```

you will get an array of **name_of_role** => **Nicename of Role**

Alternatively, you could use the global object **$wp_roles**

```
global $wp_roles;
```

Comment: Where should I put this code?

Answer (score 2):

A nice, user-friendly way of deleting your custom roles is using the [Members](https://wordpress.org/plugins/members/) plugin.

Once you install and activate it, go to **Users** > **Roles** and here you can delete an custom roles that you do not need, which you can see here:

[image]

Once you've remove the unwanted roles, you can simply delete the **Members** plugin.